# Почему не выходит подключить JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал и в начале страницы и в конце, через файл, через CDN, ничего не выходит, постоянно какие-то проблемы.

Сейчас такая проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Путь не правильный, нет расширения `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` js нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не добавили расширение .js к двум файлам.
Посмотрите внимательнее.